# Storage HDD - Missing GPT table I think, options?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, gpt

Have a 2 Tb storage volume, contained a 1 Tb NTFS volume and a 1 Tb Ext4 volume.  Spare computer, I switch it between windows and linux.

Recently put on Windows, and on first boot Windows said 'you have to check for errors', said yes, didn't think about it again.

Reboot the computer and the volume is gone.

**BIOS**

- Bios can see it.  Never been a boot device, haven't tried to boot off it.

**Windows**

- Computer management can see it but calls it uninitialized
- Diskpart can see it but gives it a capacity of 0 with no volumes
- TestDisk cannot see it

**Ubuntu Live CD**

- Gparted cannot see it
- /dev/sdc is not visible
- Gdisk cannot find it

I would like to keep the contents, but not $300 professional data recovery keep the contents.  Is a disk in such a state worth spending $50 on recovery software to try to save?  I don't believe any writes have been done considering nobody can see volumes.

Any other thoughts?

Comment: You could try TestDisk to attempt to recover the partition table (something that is unrelated to GUID Partition Table).  However, without an image of the HDD as-is, your risk any chance of data recovery (professional or novice).

Comment: Testdisk can't see it either :(

Comment: Sounds like the disk needs more help than simple software can provide.

Comment: It's not even showing up as a device, at all? Nothing in dmesg/syslog, especially if it's removable & (dis)connected, or your system supports hot swapping SATA?